# How to update an image Summernote in Laravel7?

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-7, summernote, laravel-controller

**I have a problem when updating more images on share hosting but in my local machine everything is fine**

**I got this error from my shared hosting.**

```
file_put_contents(/public/storage/article_image/post_162069532710.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

**This is my Update function**

```
        $detail=$request->messageInput;
        $dom = new \domdocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        @$dom->loadHtml('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">'.$detail);
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
      
        $images = $dom->getelementsbytagname('img');
        $bs64='base64';//variable to check the image is base64 or not
       
        foreach($images as $k => $img){
            $data = $img->getattribute('src');
            if (strpos($data,$bs64) == true)//if the Image is base 64
            {
                $data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $data));
                $image_name = "/storage/article_image/". 'post_' . time() . $k . '.png';
                $path = public_path() . $image_name;
                file_put_contents($path, $data);
                $img->removeAttribute('src');
                $img->setAttribute('src', $image_name);
                }
                else
                {
                    $image_name="".$data;
                    $img->setAttribute('src', $image_name);
                }
              };
              $detail = $dom->savehtml();

        $article=Article::find($id);
        $article->articlecategory_id=$request->articlecategory_id;
        $article->title=$request->title;
        $article->keyword=$request->keyword;
        $article->shortdetail=$request->shortdetail;
        $article->fulldetail = $detail;
        $article->updated_by=Auth::id();
        $article->status_id=$request->status_id;

        $article->save();
```

**Form upload**

```
                                        <div class="mx-auto col-md-8">
                                            {{csrf_field()}}
                                            <textarea name="messageInput" class="summernote" minlength="300" maxlength="5100" required>{{$articles->fulldetail}}</textarea>
                                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('fulldetail') }}</span>
                                        </div>
```

I stuck for about 2 days already. Please help :[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_put_contents` fails if you try to put a file in a directory that doesn't exist. In local, you had directory `/public/storage/article_image/` so you don't get this error but in shared host you don't. You should check the exist of directory before writing data to file.

```
   $data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $data)); 
   $dir = public_path() . "/storage/article_image";
    if( !is_dir( $dir ) ) {
        mkdir( $dir, 0777, true ); 
    }
    $path = $dir. '/post_' . time() . $k . '.png';
    file_put_contents($path, $data);
```